# How to get application (redux) state in React component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to react and redux. Now I build my first application that is connecting to an api server with redux. In my reducer file I'm setting the new state.
My question is how can I access that state value in a component?

Comment: You need to put a lot of code, at least all the files related, it's impossible to answer otherwise

Comment: It's all in the documentation.You need to connect your components to the store using the [`connect() hoc`](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact).

Comment: Please read the [Usage with React](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact) page in the Redux docs, as well as the tutorials listed in the [Learning Resources#Using Redux With React](https://redux.js.org/introduction/learningresources#using-redux-with-react) docs page.

Comment: here you can see an example: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/containers/VisibleTodoList.js#L1

Comment: In the future, it would help if you provide an example of your code. I'm guessing that's why this got downvoted.

Comment: @MichaelFlores No, I downvoted for asking 1) too broad and 2) the question can easily be answered by just reading the documentation or doing the tutorial or googling. The least you can expect before asking on stackoverflow is that the asker has read the official documents. "I am new to..." is not an excuse for not making at least this effort.

Comment: @trixn thanks for clarifying, hopefully this explanation will help the asker.

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect your component to the Redux store via the `connect` component, which is provided by Redux. The `connect` component requires a function to be provided called `mapStateToProps`. This function will tell Redux which items from the Redux state you want in your component.

It will look something like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { yourStateKey: state.yourStateKey }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)
```

You can learn more in the [appropriate section in the Redux docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md).

Comment: @primarykey123 if this answered your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer or elaborate on the issue you're facing.